# Google drive API with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a folder in Google drive using nodejs. I've created service account. I used JWT for client authentication and pass `mimeType= "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"`. But no folder is created.

```
  var google=require('googleapis');
  var drive=google.drive('v2');


  var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
 'myskjda3343dsdfsfd34@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
__dirname+'/my_key.pem',
  'key',
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
  '');

    authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
    }
    drive.files.insert({auth:authClient,resource:{title:"test",
    mimeType:"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}},function(err,results){
        if(err)
        { 
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(results);   
        }
```

});
});

Comment: Do you have any more information on the code you're using to make your call?

Comment: That is most unfortunate.

Comment: Either you're hitting your err handler in which case you should share that object, or you're not, the folder is being created, but it belongs to the service account, not "you" so "you" don't see it in Drive. I'm in the same situation right now and trying to figure out how to change the owner with the ID returned. I'm in shock at how difficult these Google APIs are. Do people actually use these outside of Google?